# Kotlin, string output as a number

Tags: string, kotlin

Why does the text output as a number? the vop element of the string object Vopros1 data class

var Vopros1: Vopros_1 = Vopros_1(R.string.v1.toString(), R.string.o1.toString(), R.string.o2.toString())
...
...
Column(
modifier = Modifier
.height(50.dp)
.fillMaxSize(),
horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
Text(text = Vopros1.vop)
}

data class Vopros_1(
var vop: String,
var otv1: String,
var otv2: String
){...}

I tried writing Vopros1.vop.toString() , it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

`R.string.v1` or `R.string.o1` are identifiers of the string resources and are represented as `Int` values. And adding `.toString()` here works like with any other `Int`s, simply changing, say, `123456` to `"123456"`, that's why you see numbers.

To display the actual string values, you need to provide these ids into `stringResource(...)` function: e.g., `Text(text = stringResource(R.string.v1))` will work correctly.

Comment: I need the text to be from the data class, because the objects will change, and the data class was written from resources. There is a string text in resources. But according to this scheme, some numbers are displayed instead of text.

Comment: @AlexeyL it's numerical, because `R.string.v1` is a number and `R.string.o1.toString()` is a stringified number. If you need to take it from the data class, you can change your data class property types to `Int` and pass `R.string.v1` etc. without `.toString`. And then use `Text(text = stringResource(Vopros1.vop))`